# How to reference a dll that may be missing

Tags: .net, dll, reference, dotnetnuke

We have a Learning Management System that that installs into the DotNetNuke framework as a module set.  We would like to add some extensions to our LMS that utilize some API calls provided by a third party module.  The third party module is quite expensive and not all of our clients will want to buy it.  So we will have to make the extensions optional and disable them if the third party module is not present.

Here is my question.  How can we structure our software so that it can run with or without the third party DLLs being present?  If we make references to the third party DLLs for the API methods, then I think we will have run time errors if the third party module is not installed even if we disable those features.

How can we avoid run time errors for clients who do not have the third party module installed?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You may need **Reflection**, instead of referencing third party DLLs at compile time, with "Add Reference", load it dynamically at RunTime using Assembly.Load method.

If client has installed required framework - do whatever you  need, if not - no compile or other errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not execute any code that calls to an assembly, your app will function without the assembly being present.  Even without doing any reflection tricks.

I have done this in the past by guaranteeing that no code calls to the 3rd party assembly with dependency injection and on app startup, not registering any implementations that reference the 3rd party. Instead, register a different implementation or a stub implementation.

Or any other means of guaranteeing that no code that calls to the 3rd party is called.